# php.ini file for eclipse php debugging

Tags: debugging, xampp, php-ini

I have been searching high and low and still cannot get debugging working with 'eclipse for PHP Developers 3.0.2'.

At the moment eclipse is just hanging at 57% with 'Launching: waiting for XDebug session. But while eclipse is hanging, the php file opens in an external browser and runs???

I'm using 'XAMPP 3.1.0.3.1.0' for the web server and have the appropriate 'php_xdebug.dll' file in the php ext folder.

I have tried numerous setting from other forums but still no luck, here is my php.ini file config for XDebug:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dllstack"
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 0n
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "\xampp\tmp"
```

Anyone have an idea to what I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the configuration setting were not correct, good tool to use is http://xdebug.org/wizard.php.

Downloaded new version, added it the php/ext and updated php.ini:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = \xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.2-5.4-vc9.dll
;zend_extension = "\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
;xdebug.remote_enable = 0
;xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
;xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "\xampp\tmp"
```